# Нужно ли запятую ставить?

Tags: пунктуация

Думаешь слабость? Нужна ли запятая после слова"думаешь"

Answer (score 3):

Запятая ставится: **Думаешь, слабость?**

Глагол в функции вводного слова (=по-твоему).

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна: здесь неполное сложноподчинённое предложение (в отличие от простого "Думаешь думу?"), придаточную часть которого нужно отделить. Полное было бы таким:

> Ты думаешь, что это слабость?