# Остается ли запятая после того, как мы убираем союз?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, вводные-слова

*Думаешь, **что** к этому причастен кто-то, живущий на луне?*
Если мы убираем из этого предложения союз "что", остается ли у нас при этом запятая после "думаешь"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432313   вводное слово: скажешь, думаешь

Comment: @Liads1  На сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные ответы и вопросы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также отмечать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ты] *Думаешь, что к этому причастен кто-то, живущий на луне?*
Это сложноподчиненное предложение; в главном предложении подразумевается подлежащее "ты", "думаешь" — сказуемое.

*Думаешь, к этому причастен кто-то, живущий на луне?*
Запятая остается. Это простое предложение, оно осложнено вводным словом "думаешь" (после него по правилам нужна запятая) и обособленным определительным оборотом.
Вводное слово "думаешь" можно убрать из предложения или переставить в другое место без потери смысла. (Сравните: *К этому, думаешь, причастен кто-то, живущий на луне?* В первом предложении такая "рокировка" невозможна.)

Выходит, это Шацкий их сдал? ― Безусловно. ― **Думаешь,** к нему Писец идет? ― А к кому еще? Я в такие совпадения не верю, ― твердо сказал Гусев. [Олег Дивов. Выбраковка (1999)]

*— **Думаешь,** к этому причастен Аматаниди? – прошептала я* (М. Цура. Солнцеликий).

[Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121)